# How to refresh the Firebase Push Notification swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I using firebase push notification in my application when the user install the application into his device on the first time the following method is called.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

//Firebase Configure
FirebaseApp.configure()

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
} else {
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

return true
   }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

// Print full message.
print(userInfo)
   }

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
             fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

// Print full message.
print(userInfo)

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
 }





    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
// TODO: If necessary send token to application server.

defaultValues.set(fcmToken, forKey: "FCMToken")
defaultValues.synchronize()

  }
 @available(iOS 10, *)

extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert])
}

  }

// MARK: - Push Notification MessagingDelegate methods.


  extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate{

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.

    defaultValues.set(fcmToken, forKey: "FCMToken")
    defaultValues.synchronize()

    //Call Sending device info to api.
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

    defaultValues.set(fcmToken, forKey: "FCMToken")
    defaultValues.synchronize()

    //Call Sending device info to api.
    Helper.shared.appDelegate.SendingDeviceInfo()
}


func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Message data:", remoteMessage.appData)
}

 }
```

when the user is press login button I hit the api.
But my issue is when the user is logout and again login same api again hitting but with nil fcm token.
At logout time I clear all defaults data.
How to we fix this issue any one help to me.

This is my logout code

```
func loggout(){
        //logout and reset root controller - Delete all userdefaults data.

        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

        //Clear All Default values
        let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
        defaultValues.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
        defaultValues.synchronize()
        setRootControllerBeforeLogin()
    }
```

I send fcm token to server with this method I call this method in login button action.

```
func SendingDeviceInfo(){ 
        let fcmvalue = defaultValues.string(forKey: "FCMToken") ?? "" 
        let param:[String:Any] = ["registerID":fcmvalue]

        WebService.shared.apiDataPostMethod(url: deviceInfoURL, parameters: param) { (response, error) in
            if error == nil
            {
                print(param)
            }else{
               // print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**didReceiveRegistrationToken of firebase is only called when you call register for push notification.**

**Your Problem** - When you logout you clear UserDefaults, so “FCMToken” has nil value

**Solution**- 1. First of all no need to clear  “FCMToken” from UserDefaults, because you will get same token when you launch app next time(that’s not always the case).Firebase token can change any time but not so soon. And one more thing, if you install the app and run first time, it will always generate new token.

2. When you logout and login again, call register for push notification(Firebase) again.You will get token again but changes are more that you will get same token.

**Edit**
You can get the value of token from UserDefaults before deleting it and assign it later again.

```
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "FCMToken")
        if let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
            UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain)
      }
     UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "FCMToken")
```

Comment: Hello I write this code for clear defaults

 let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
 defaultValues.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
 defaultValues.synchronize()

Comment: this is working but when the user is logout and again login with new user then generate new token in this case it is failure.

Comment: @sriknth Can you show your code that how you are trying to generate new token when user login after logout.

Comment: @sriknth Ok but still can't see when user logout and login again(assuming without closing app), how are you able to generate token again.

Comment: Actually I don't having idea on that due to that reason only I rise query here. again I called the didReceiveRegistrationToken method in logout case.

Comment: @sriknth show your logout function and from where you register for push notification. It will be good if you can share your code.

Comment: I shared my entire code I save fcm token in didRefreshRegistrationToken and didReceiveRegistrationToken methods, I send those in SendingDeviceInfo() method call that method in sign in button, I remove entire defaults in logout this is issue, once see my code.

Comment: But I told you not to remove "FCMToken" from userdefaults

Comment: yes I write that in logout case when I logout and again login with different user on that time also it gives same fcm token is it correct.

Comment: Yes its absolutely fine.But remember that when you send notifications, do not send it to the user which are logout. Otherwise  one device will receive multiple notifications, for the user which is currently login, and the user which has just logout, as they have same token.

Comment: Ok Thank you @Vikky you give 2 solutions we are follow the way 1. how to we make way2

Comment: Ok then the second solution will be, whenever you want that your "didReceiveRegistrationToken" should be triggered, you should call "registerForRemoteNotifications" function again.